# Highlight Solr query results using a dictionary of words

Tags: solr, highlighting

I've got a dictionary file containing about 300K words and I would like to highlight these words whenever they appear in the results of a query.

I know how to use highlighting and I know that I can concatenate boolean statements in my query parameter, but I don't believe that using 300K boolean statements in a query is possible/ideal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Solr's highlighting is designed to work with user input. As such it expects only few parameters. Did you consider to store the highlighting information at index-time?

Comment: Yes, but I'll still need to highlight every word from my dictionary file, which lead to using a very long boolean statement in the query, or several queries.

Comment: What I wanted to express is, when indexing a document, you may at that point of time surround every word in that document that belongs to that dictionary with highlighting tags. Then when searching, you just display the content and the words will be highlighted right away.

Comment: I'm indexing a lot of documents and it will not be a suitable solution for performance and speed reasons. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, Solr highlighting component is exactly what I need, but I would like to load a word list and highlight them in the results.